# Task Manager Won't Let Me Set Task Priority

Tags: task-management, process-priority

When I go into task manager, everything acts normal except for my laptop being slow. But when I select priority, and try to change it, it gives me the massage "An error was encountered by setting priority to the PID 1904. It is likely that you don't have the required privileges," but I am on the admin and original account on this laptop. If anyone know how to fix this, or another task manager that works for stopping task/ apps and setting priorities, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, I tried opening task manager using the terminal command "sudo xfce-taskmanager" and I was able to open it with privileged access but I think it doesn't launch with privileges by default because you can accidentally really mess stuff up. Sorry I'm pretty new to Ubuntu too, so I don't really have much more information.